# How to find the minimum number of moves to move an item into a position in a stack?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, stack, dynamic-programming

[image: Stacks]

Given a set of NXP stacks with N being the number of stacks, and P being the stacks capacity, how can I calculate the minimum number of swaps needed to move from some node in location A to some arbitrary location B? I'm designing a game, and the end goal is to sort all of the stacks so that they are all the same color.

```
# Let "-" represent blank spaces, and assume the stacks are
stacks = [
           ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], 
           ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 
           ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G'], 
           ['-', '-', '-', 'B'], 
           ['-', 'B', 'B', 'B']
         ]
```

If I want to insert a "B" at `stacks[1][1]` such that `stacks[1] = ["-", "B", "Y", "Y"]`. How can I determine the minimum number of moves required to do so?

I've been looking at multiple approaches, I've tried genetic algorithms that generate all possible moves from a state, score them, and then continue down the best scoring paths, I've also attempted to run Djikstra's algorithm for pathfinding on the problem. It seems frustratingly simple, yet I can't figure out a way to get it to run in anything other than exponential time. Is there an algorithm I'm missing that is applicable here?

### Edit

I've written this function to calculate the minimum number of moves required:
stacks: List of List of Characters representing the pieces in the stack, stacks[0][0] is the top of stack[0]
stack_ind: The index of the stack that the piece will be added to
needs_piece: The piece that should be added to the stack
needs_index: The index where the piece should be located

```
def calculate_min_moves(stacks, stack_ind, needs_piece, needs_index):
    # Minimum moves needed to empty the stack that will receive the piece so that it can hold the piece
    num_removals = 0
    for s in stacks[stack_ind][:needs_index+1]:
        if item != "-":
            num_removals += 1

    min_to_unlock = 1000
    unlock_from = -1
    for i, stack in enumerate(stacks):
        if i != stack_ind:
            for k, piece in enumerate(stack):
                if piece == needs_piece:
                    if k < min_to_unlock:
                        min_to_unlock = k
                        unlock_from = i

    num_free_spaces = 0
    free_space_map = {}

    for i, stack in enumerate(stacks):
        if i != stack_ind and i != unlock_from:
            c = stack.count("-")
            num_free_spaces += c
            free_space_map[i] = c

    if num_removals + min_to_unlock <= num_free_spaces:
        print("No shuffling needed, there's enough free space to move all the extra nodes out of the way")
    else:
        # HERE
        print("case 2, things need shuffled")
```

Edit:
Test Cases on stacks:

```
stacks = [
           ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], 
           ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 
           ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G'], 
           ['-', '-', '-', 'B'], 
           ['-', 'B', 'B', 'B']
         ]

Case 1: stacks[4][1] should be 'G'
Move 'B' from stacks[4][1] to stacks[3][2]
Move 'G' from stacks[2][0] to stacks[4][1]
num_removals = 0 # 'G' is directly accessible as the top of stack 2
min_to_unlock = 1 # stack 4 has 1 piece that needs removed
free_spaces = 3 # stack 3 has free spaces and no pieces need moved to or from it
moves = [[4, 3], [2, 4]]
min_moves = 2
# This is easy to calculate
Case 2: stacks[0][3] should be 'B'
Move 'B' from stacks[3][3] to stack[4][0]
Move 'R' from stacks[0][0] to stacks[3][3]
Move 'R' from stacks[0][1] to stacks[3][2]
Move 'R' from stacks[0][2] to stacks[3][1]
Move 'R' from stacks[0][3] to stacks[3][0]
Move 'B' from stacks[4][0] to stacks[0][3]
num_removals = 0 # 'B' is directly accessible 
min_to_unlock = 4 # stack 0 has 4 pieces that need removed
free_spaces = 3 # If stack 3 and 4 were switched this would be 1
moves = [[3, 4], [0, 3], [0, 3], [0, 3], [0, 3], [4, 0]]
min_moves = 6
#This is hard to calculate
```

The actual code implementation isn't the part that is difficult, it's determining an how to implement an algorithm that solves the problem that I'm struggling with.

As per @YonIif's request I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/TristenHarr/16d49f594749f2068f706cd20a142ae3) for the problem.

When it runs, it generates a random array of the stacks, and chooses a random piece that needs to be inserted into a random stack at a random location.

Running it prints something of this format to the console.

```
All Stacks: [['-', '-', 'O', 'Y'], ['-', 'P', 'P', 'O'], ['-', 'P', 'O', 'Y'], ['Y', 'Y', 'O', 'P']]
Stack 0 is currently ['-', '-', 'O', 'Y']
Stack 0 should be ['-', '-', '-', 'P']
```

### Status update

I'm very determined to solve this problem *somehow*.

Keep in mind that there are way's to minimize the number of cases, such as the ones @Hans Olsson mentioned in the comments. My most recent approach to this problem, has been to develop a set of rules similar to those mentioned, and employ them in a generational algorithm.

Rules such as:

Don't ever reverse a move. Go from 1->0 then 0->1 (Makes no sense)

Don't ever move a piece twice in a row. Never Move from 0 -> 1 then 1 -> 3

Given some move from stacks[X] to stacks[Y], then some number of moves, then a move from stacks[Y] to stacks[Z], if stacks[Z] is in the same state as it was when the move from stacks[X] to stacks[Y] occurred, a move could've been eliminated by moving from stacks[X] directly to stacks[Z]

Currently, I am approaching this problem with an attempt to create enough rules, that it minimizes the number of "valid" moves, enough so that an answer can be calculated using a generational algorithm. If anyone can think of additional rules, I'd be interested in hearing them in the comments.

### Update

Thanks to the answer by @RootTwo I've had a bit of a breakthrough, which I will outline here.

**Onto the breakthrough**

Define the goal height as the depth the goal piece must be placed in the 
destination stack.

Whenever some goal piece is placed at index <= stack_height - goal height,
there will always be a shortest path to victory via the clear_path() method.

```
Let S represent some solid Piece.
```

I.E.

```
Stacks = [ [R, R, G], [G, G, R], [-, -, -] ]
Goal = Stacks[0][2] = R
Goal Height = 2.
Stack Height - Goal Height = 0
```

Given some stack such that `stack[0] = R`, the game is won.

```
                       GOAL
[ [ (S | -), (S | -), (S | -) ], [R, S, S], [(S | - ), (S | -), (S | -)] ]
```

Since it is known that their are always at least stack_height blank spaces 
available, the worst possible case would be:

```
 [ [ S, S, !Goal ], [R, S, S], [-, -, -]
```

Since we know the goal piece cannot be in the goal destination or the game is won. 
In which case the minimum number of moves required would be the moves:

```
(0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (1, 0)

Stacks = [ [R, G, G], [-, R, R], [-, -, G] ]
Goal = Stack[0][1] = R
Stack Height - Goal Height = 1
```

Given some stack such that `stack[1] = R`, the game is won.

```
              GOAL
[ [ (S | -), (S | -), S], [ (S | -), R, S], [(S | -), (S | -), (S | -)]
```

We know there are at least 3 blank spaces available, so the worst possible case would be:

```
[ [ S, !Goal, S], [S, R, S], [ -, -, - ]
```

In this case the minimum number of moves would be the moves:

```
(1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (1, 0)
```

This will hold for all cases.

Thus, the problem has been reduced to a problem of finding the minimum number of 
moves required to place the goal piece at or above at the goal height.

This splits the problem into a series of sub-problems:

1. When the destination stack has its accessible piece != goal piece, 
   determining if there is a valid location for that piece, or if the piece should 
   stay there while another piece is swapped.
2. When the destination stack has its accessible piece == goal piece, 
   determining if it can be removed and placed at the required goal height, or if 
   the piece should stay while another is swapped.
3. When the above two cases require another piece to be swapped, 
   determining which pieces to swap in order to increase to make it possible for the 
   goal piece to reach the goal height.

The destination stack should always have its cases evaluated first.

I.E.

```
stacks = [ [-, R, G], [-, R, G], [-, R, G] ]

Goal = stacks[0][1] = G
```

Checking the Goal Stack first leads to:

```
(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0) = 4 Moves
```

Ignoring the Goal Stack:

```
(1, 0), (1, 2), (0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0) = 5 Moves
```

Comment: Consider adding test cases i.e. sample inputs and outputs for those.

Comment: Have you tried [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)? It's fairly similar to Dijkstra's algorithm but sometimes it is considerably faster.

Comment: The problem I've encountered with pathfinding algorithms is that you have to represent each game state as a node. Representing the game state requires ~ 16!/(4!*4!*4!*4!) nodes, for a 4X4 gameboard. That's running a pathfinding algorithm on ~24,000,000 nodes for a 4X4, and the game board increases in size to up to 8X8. @Yonlif The algorithm I'm searching for will likely be something greedy.

Comment: This sounds like a competition problem, do you have upper bounds on the parameters?

Comment: It's actually for a game I'm designing! It's what I'm going to use to calculate the minimum number of moves from a starting mixed up set of stacks, to get to the win-state of everything sorted. (As well as to give players a "hint" option when they get stuck) Upper bounds would be the maximum board size being 8X8. I'm using a genetic algorithm to calculate the minimum number of moves with a seperate scoring function, but I'm hoping to speed it up using this. @kevmo314

Comment: Can you please share a github repo link? I would like to experiment myself if it is okay. @Tristen

Comment: @Tristen interesting, I think it would be difficult to find an efficient algorithm that can handle beyond 4x4x4, as it does sound like this will be isomorphic to a pathfinding problem. Since this is for a game, perhaps one approach would be to scrap the "shortest" requirement? If there are movement primitives, eg dig out a block from below then restore the stack, that would allow a solution to be constructed. Up to you if that works in the context of your game though, otherwise I would use something like A* and just score the possible moves, ie not find a full path :)

Comment: After a first look, this problem seems NP-hard. It is probably not within NP (not NP-complete), because even if I give you an optimal solution, you cannot even verify it easily. This is notorious for optimization problems on permutations. I'd suggest to cross-post the problem at [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Look into approxmiation algorithms for this issue. This is a pretty hard problem but a decent approximation should exist. This is similar: [Arbitrary Towers of Hanoi](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11562/towers-of-hanoi-but-with-arbitrary-initial-and-final-configuration)

Comment: @DarioHett That was what I was worried about! I had my fingers crossed that it wouldn't end up being an NP-Hard problem, but I also had a gut feeling it might be one. I have been having better luck with a genetic algorithm, and also some specialized scoring functions that score the moves. I'll take a look at the Arbitrary Towers of Hanoi! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be minimum number of moves or will it do if we can find a solution in polynomial time?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda The worst case I'd be satisfied with would be within 1-2 moves of the minimum number of moves guaranteed. It's easy to solve it with an unlimited number of moves using algorithms that say, first shuffle the piece until it's at the top of some stack, and empty the stack it needs to be in. As people, our brains are capable of figuring out the minimum number of moves, or relatively close to it for most cases. (With a bit of thought and maybe a few attempts) If it's easy to do it in less moves than the algorithm solves it in, then it becomes pointless, and the game becomes too easy.

Comment: @Tristen, Have you considered of instead of generating the puzzle randomly (e.g. with `random.shuffle()` like in your code), you start from a sorted stack, then moving the pieces randomly but within the set of possible moves? This might not necessarily give you the minimum number of moves to reorder the stacks, but at least you know it's possible to get to an ordered state and have an upper bound/baseline.

Comment: If you try to generate the puzzle randomly - remember to remove obviously redundant moves (moving something back after a forward move or doing a move in two steps when one would suffice; and also in combination with possibly unrelated moves mixed in).

Comment: I like to solve such quizzes. Please take a look of my implementation https://gist.github.com/FerumFlex/404b2bb02ac9f063ffb504ef1c72621e

Comment: @GrandPhuba I have done something similar to that. With the way the stacks are setup, no matter how you shuffle them, there always will exist a valid move. If the stacks are N tall, then there will always be N empty spaces. So, it's always possible to get to the wanted state. As for the upper bound/baseline I have done a little bit of work on that, but unless the upper bound can somehow be translated to the lower bound, it's trivial to find it! Appreciate the comment though. I use the random configurations to assure I don't simply write something to solves edge cases only!

Comment: @AntonPomieshchenko That's similar to what I had a while back! It also encounters the same problem that led to me posting this question :) try running it with a 5X6 with 5 stacks, and 6 pieces, some cases chug along for quite a while. (Sometimes takes over an hour to run, if the pc doesn't freeze first!)

Comment: @halfer Thank you for letting me know. I've edited it and brought back the code into the question. I had a single external link to a gist previously, it's not highly relevant and if that's against community guidelines I can remove it from the question completely if needed!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, great stuff. Personally I think external links are fine as a supplementary, as long as the code (or the most relevant bit of code) is also in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with two options, but none of them are able to solve case 2 in a timely manner. The first option is using A* with a string distance measure as your h(n), second option is IDA*. I tested many string similarity measures, i used smith-waterman on my approach. I have changed your notation to treat the problem faster. I have added numbers to the end of each digit to check if a piece was moved twice.

Here are the cases I have tested on:

```
start = [
 ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4'], 
 ['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4'], 
 ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4'], 
 ['B1'], 
 ['B2', 'B3', 'B4']
]

case_easy = [
 ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], 
 ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 
 ['G', 'G', 'G'], 
 ['B', 'B'], 
 ['B', 'B', 'G']
]


case_medium = [
 ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], 
 ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'B'], 
 ['G', 'G', 'G'], 
 ['B'],
 ['B', 'B', 'G', 'Y']
]

case_medium2 = [
 ['R', 'R', 'R' ], 
 ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'B'], 
 ['G', 'G' ], 
 ['B', 'R', 'G'],
 ['B', 'B', 'G', 'Y']
]

case_hard = [
 ['B'], 
 ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 
 ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G'], 
 ['R','R','R', 'R'], 
 ['B','B', 'B']
]
```

Here's the A* code:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from heapq import *
import time, sys
import textdistance
import os

def a_star(b, goal, h):
    print("A*")
    start_time = time.time()
    heap = [(-1, b)]
    bib = {}
    bib[b.stringify()] = b

    while len(heap) > 0:
        node = heappop(heap)[1]
        if node == goal:
            print("Number of explored states: {}".format(len(bib)))
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            print("Execution time {}".format(elapsed_time))
            return rebuild_path(node)

        valid_moves = node.get_valid_moves()
        children = node.get_children(valid_moves)
        for m in children:
          key = m.stringify()
          if key not in bib.keys():
            h_n = h(key, goal.stringify())
            heappush(heap, (m.g + h_n, m)) 
            bib[key] = m

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("Execution time {}".format(elapsed_time))
    print('No Solution')
```

Here's the IDA* Code:

```
#shows the moves done to solve the puzzle
def rebuild_path(state):
    path = []
    while state.parent != None:
        path.insert(0, state)
        state = state.parent
    path.insert(0, state)
    print("Number of steps to solve: {}".format(len(path) - 1))
    print('Solution')

def ida_star(root, goal, h):
    print("IDA*")
    start_time = time.time()
    bound = h(root.stringify(), goal.stringify())
    path = [root]
    solved = False
    while not solved:
        t = search(path, 0, bound, goal, h)
        if type(t) == Board:
            solved = True
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            print("Execution time {}".format(elapsed_time))
            rebuild_path(t)
            return t
        bound = t

def search(path, g, bound, goal, h):

    node = path[-1]
    time.sleep(0.005)
    f = g + h(node.stringify(), goal.stringify())

    if f > bound: return f
    if node == goal:
        return node

    min_cost = float('inf')
    heap = []
    valid_moves = node.get_valid_moves()
    children = node.get_children(valid_moves)
    for m in children:
      if m not in path:
        heappush(heap, (m.g + h(m.stringify(), goal.stringify()), m)) 

    while len(heap) > 0:
        path.append(heappop(heap)[1])
        t = search(path, g + 1, bound, goal, h)
        if type(t) == Board: return t
        elif t < min_cost: min_cost = t
        path.pop()
    return min_cost

class Board:
  def __init__(self, board, parent=None, g=0, last_moved_piece=''):
    self.board = board
    self.capacity = len(board[0])
    self.g = g
    self.parent = parent
    self.piece = last_moved_piece

  def __lt__(self, b):
    return self.g < b.g

  def __call__(self):
    return self.stringify()

  def __eq__(self, b):
    if self is None or b is None: return False
    return self.stringify() == b.stringify()

  def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([' '.join([j[0] for j in i]) for i in self.board])+'\n\n'

  def stringify(self):
    b=''
    for i in self.board:
      a = ''.join([j[0] for j in i])
      b += a + '-' * (self.capacity-len(a))

    return b

  def get_valid_moves(self):
    pos = []
    for i in range(len(self.board)):
      if len(self.board[i]) < self.capacity:
        pos.append(i)
    return pos

  def get_children(self, moves):
    children = []
    for i in range(len(self.board)):
      for j in moves:
        if i != j and self.board[i][-1] != self.piece:
          a = deepcopy(self.board)
          piece = a[i].pop()
          a[j].append(piece)
          children.append(Board(a, self, self.g+1, piece))
    return children
```

Usage:

```
initial = Board(start)
final1 = Board(case_easy)
final2 = Board(case_medium)
final2a = Board(case_medium2)
final3 = Board(case_hard)

x = textdistance.gotoh.distance

a_star(initial, final1, x)
a_star(initial, final2, x)
a_star(initial, final2a, x)

ida_star(initial, final1, x)
ida_star(initial, final2, x)
ida_star(initial, final2a, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you said there are N stacks with capacity P, and there are always P empty spaces.  If that is the case, it seems this algorithm will work in the `else` clause in your code (i.e. when `num_removals + min_to_unlock > num_free_spaces`):

1. Find the desired piece that is closest to the top of a stack.
2. Move all the pieces from above the desired piece in such a way that there is one stack (not the destination stack) that has an empty space on top.  If needed, move pieces from the destination stack or another stack.  If the only open space is the top of the destination stack, move a piece there to open the top of another stack.  This is always possible, because there are P open spaces and at most P-1 pieces to move from above the desired piece.
3. Move the desired piece to the empty spot on top of a stack.
4. Move pieces from the destination stack until the destination is open.
5. Move the desired piece to the destination.

Comment: I've spent the past couple hours digging into this answer, and I think there might be something there. If possible, could you provide a bit more information as to how you'd go about moving the pieces that are above the desired piece? How do you determine which stacks to move them to? Perhaps a bit of psuedocode/code. This is definitely the closest I've felt to the solving this so far.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven’t found the time to prove this mathematically, I decided to post this anyway; hope it helps. The approach is to define a parameter p that decreases with good moves and reaches zero exactly when the game has finished. In the program only considers good moves or neutral moves (that leave p unchanged) and forget about bad moves (that increase p).

So what is p? For every column define p as the number of blocks that still have to be removed before all colors in that column are the desired color. So suppose we want the red blocks to end up in the leftmost column (I’ll come back to that later), and suppose there is one red block at the bottom, then a yellow on top of that, one more block on top of that, and then an empty space. Then p=2 for this column (two blocks to remove before all are red). Calculate p for all columns. For the column that should end up empty, p is equal to the number of blocks that is in it (all of them should go). P for the current state is the sum of all p’s for all columns.

When p=0, all columns have the same color and one column is empty, so the game has finished.

By choosing moves that decrease p (or at least not increase p) we’re moving in the right direction, this is in my opinion the crucial difference with shortest path algorithms: Dijkstra had no idea whether he was moving in the right direction with every vertex he was investigating.

So how do we determine where each color should end up? Basically by determining p for every possibility. So e.g. start with red / yellow / green / empty, calculate p, then go to red / yellow / empty / green, calculate p, etc. Take the starting position with the lowest p. This takes n! calculations. For n=8 this is 40320, which is doable. The bad news is that you’ll have to examine all starting positions with equal lowest p. The good news is that you can forget the rest.

There are two mathematical uncertainties here. One: is it possible that there is a shorter path that uses a bad move? Seems unlikely, I haven’t found a counterexample , but I haven’t found a proof either. Two: is it possible that when starting with a non-optimal starting position (I.e. not the lowest p) there would be a shorter path than with all optimal starting positions. Again: no counterexample but no proof either.

Some implementation suggestions. Keeping track of p during execution for each column is not difficult but should of course be done. Another parameter that should be kept for each column is the number of open spots. If 0, then this columns can momentarily not accept any blocks, so can be left out of the loop. When p=0 for a column, it is not eligible for a pop. For every possible pop, examine if there is a good move, I.e. one which decreases the overall p. If there are multiple, examine all. If there is none, consider all neutral moves.

All of this should greatly reduce your computation time.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question! Although this is the motivation behind the question. The question is to find the minimum number of moves to move a single piece, to a single location. The question was not to find the minimum number of moves to sort the stacks, although that is the motivation behind the question. However, with that scoring of P, you would be incorrect. There are many instances where there are "bad moves" that end up increasing P at first, and then later decrease it at a faster rate. With that said, perhaps re-read the question as your answer has no relevance.

Comment: My apologies Tristen, I did indeed not read the question carefully. I was fascinated by the mathematical aspect of it and, being late to the party, too quick to answer. I'll be more careful next time. Hopefully you do find an answer.